# Row/Column major storage scheme of a matrix

Tags: tikz-arrows

Hello I want to draw a tikzpicture to pictorially row major (for C++/C) and column major (FOTRAN) storage scheme of a 2D array, a picture similar to below (**row major storage ,C++ layout**):

[image: row major storage for a 2D array]

So far I've been able to generate a code that draws the  boxes but I'm unsure of how to draw the arrows that follows the pattern shown in above picture. The code looks like this :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%xscale = 1.25 will increase horizontal size and spacing
%yscale with a negative sign makes the (0,0) at the top right corner
[>=stealth,x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1.25]

 \foreach \x in  {0,...,4}
    \foreach \y in  {0,...,4 }
     \foreach \position in {(50*\x,50*\y)}
            { \draw[thick] \position rectangle +(30,30) node[pos=0.5] {(\y,\x)} ;}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The resulting image is :

[image: what I have so far]

It'll be really helpful if someone could tell me the correct way to draw tikz arrows for a row major format (and a column major format in which the arrows start vertically top to bottom from first column with the arrow head endng at the bottom of last column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your own solution is already quite nice. Here come some suggestions that may make it easier to place the brackets.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(1pt,0)},y={(0,1pt)}]
\draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,-stealth] (-20,0) 
\foreach \y in {0,...,3}
{ --  (250,-50*\y) arc(90:-90:12.5)
--  (-20,-25-50*\y) arc(90:270:12.5)
-- (-20,-50-50*\y) -- (250, -50-50*\y)
} --(255,-200);
\foreach \x in  {0,...,4}
{\foreach \y in {0,...,4}
 { \node[draw,fill=white] at (12.5+50*\x,-50*\y) (X-\x-\y){(\x,\y)};}
} 
\node[left=1mm of X-0-0] {[};
\path (X-3-0) -- (X-4-0) node[midway]{][};
\path (X-2-1) -- (X-3-1) node[midway]{][};
\path (X-1-2) -- (X-2-2) node[midway]{][};
\path (X-0-3) -- (X-1-3) node[midway]{][};
\node[left=1mm of X-0-4] {][};
\path (X-3-4) -- (X-4-4) node[midway]{][};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My solution for a row major storage scheme so far looks like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1.25,color=black,line width=1.25mm, opacity=1]
%xscale = 1.25 will increase horizontal size and spacing
%yscale with a negative sign makes the (0,0) at the top right corner

%boxes with numbers
 \foreach \x in  {0,...,4}
    \foreach \y in  {0,...,4 }
     \foreach \position in {(50*\x,50*\y)}
            { \draw[thick] \position rectangle +(30,30) node[pos=0.5] {(\y,\x)} ;}

%lines through the boxes
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [->,>=stealth,color=black,line width=1.25mm, opacity=1]
\foreach \x in {0,...,5}
\foreach \y in {0,...,4}
{\draw  (-20+50*\x,15+50*\y) -- (00+50*\x,15+50*\y);
}
\draw[arrow] (230,215) -- (270,215);  %arrow head at box (4,4)

%arcs at the end
\foreach \y in {0,...,3}
{\draw  (250,15+50*\y) arc(270:455:12.5); 
\draw (-20,65+50*\y) arc(90:270:12.5);
\draw (-22,40+50*\y) -- (251, 40+50*\y);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The resulting picture is  looks like below :

[image: my soln so far]

**Update 1 (7th June): Addition of code for column major format**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1.25,color=black,line width=1.25mm, opacity=1]

 \foreach \x in  {0,...,4}
    \foreach \y in  {0,...,4 }
     \foreach \position in {(50*\x,50*\y)}
            { \draw[thick] \position rectangle +(30,30) node[pos=0.5] {(\y,\x)} ;} %boxes with numbers

%lines through the boxes
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [->,>=stealth,line width=1.25mm, opacity=1]
\foreach \x in {0,...,5}
\foreach \y in {0,...,4}
{\draw (15+50*\y,-20+50*\x) -- (15+50*\y,00+50*\x);
}
\draw[arrow] (215,230) -- (215,270);  %arrow head at box (4,4)

\foreach \y in {0,...,3}
{\draw  (15+50*\y,250) arc(180:00:12.5)  ; %bottom arcs
\draw (40+50*\y,-20) arc(-180:1:12.5); %top arcs
\draw (40+50*\y, -20) -- (40+50*\y, 250)  ; %vertical lines in between boxes
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The resulting tikzpicture is :

[image: my soln for col major storage format]

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, a solution using an auto-filled matrix and one path on background.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    arraynode/.style={
        draw,
        fill=white,
        node contents={(\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1\relax,
                        \the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-1\relax)},
        alias=n\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1\relax\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-1\relax
        },
    array/.style={%
        matrix of math nodes,
        nodes = arraynode,
        column sep=5mm,
        row sep={1cm,between origins},  %<-No space before `between` 
        nodes in empty cells}, 
]

\matrix[array] {
&&&&\\
&&&&\\
&&&&\\
&&&&\\
&&&&\\};

\node at ([xshift=-2.5mm]n00.west) {$[$};
\foreach \i in {40,31,22,13,04,44}
    \node at ([xshift=-2.5mm]n\i.west) {$][$};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[-{LaTeX}, line width=3pt, black!30] ([xshift=-7.5mm]n00.west) 
      foreach \i [count=\ni from 0] in {0,...,3}{
         -- ([xshift=5mm]n\i4.east) arc(90:-90:2.5mm)
         -- ([shift={(-5mm,-5mm)}]n\i0.west) arc(90:270:2.5mm)}
         -- ([xshift=7.5mm]n44.east);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    arraynode/.style={
        draw,
        fill=white,
        node contents={(\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1\relax,
                        \the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-1\relax)},
        alias=n\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1\relax\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-1\relax
        },
    array/.style={%
        matrix of math nodes,
        nodes = arraynode,
        column sep={14mm,between origins}, %<-No space before `between`
        row sep=5mm, 
        nodes in empty cells}, 
]

\matrix[array] {
&&&&\\
&&&&\\
&&&&\\
&&&&\\
&&&&\\};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[-{LaTeX}, line width=3pt, black!30] ([yshift=7.5mm]n00.north) 
        foreach \i [count=\ni from 0] in {0,...,3}{
           -- ([yshift=-5mm]n4\i.south) arc(180:360:3.5mm)
           -- ([shift={(7mm,5mm)}]n0\i.north) arc(180:0:3.5mm)}
           -- ([yshift=-7.5mm]n44.south);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]